# What is the difference between "leave" and "leave behind"?

Tags: difference

Tell me please what is the difference between *leave* and *leave behind* in the following contexts.

> I have **left** my bag **behind** at the store.
>
> I have **left** my bag at the store.
>
> He **left** his family **behind** and went out of the country.
>
> He **left** his family and went out of the country.

Comment: We don't usually include the optional preposition ***behind*** if we're explicitly naming *where* something was left. So if I heard your first example from a native speaker, I'd be looking for some subtle nuance of meaning that might have led the speaker to include it. And very likely I'd guess he meant he'd *deliberately* left it behind (so as to have an excuse to go back for it, and carry on chatting up the pretty sales assistant! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers interesting, I would say I've "left my bag behind at the store" (or wherever) if I realised later that I didn't have my bag with me, wondered where it was, and concluded I'd left it [behind] at the store! Or as it happens to me more frequently (I'm a bit absent minded...) - oh no, I've left my [security fob, ID, the letter I meant to put in the mail... you name it, I've forgotten it!] behind!!

On the other hand - to "leave your family behind" usually means that you went on ahead alone for some reason, whereas to "leave your family" has a more.. permanent connotation!

Comment: After thinking about this a bit more - I think the distinction is that "to leave something behind" is in contrast to an expectation that you would typically take the thing with you. "To leave something [in a place]" is a more neutral statement that you left it in its current place. But "leaving your family" still has a different implication, without any other information the person who "left his family and went out of the country" would be assumed to have left them 'permanently' by most native english speakers. In that case he is leaving "from" the family unit.